# Convert C code removing apparent pointers

Tags: c, pointers, converters

I am a computer science student and have a C game project to do.
I started the project several weeks ago and now realized I am not allowed to use pointers at all because our teacher said so (we're not supposed to have seen them).  But my code is full of them, really!

What I mean by "not using pointers" is "not using *apparent* pointers". For instance, using an array is completely fine since we don't know what happens behind the scene.

So I thought of using a regular expression to convert all my code as follows:

```
void increment(int *a){
  (*a)++;
}
int a = 12;
increment(&a);
printf("%d", a);
```

to

```
void increment(int a[1]){
  a[0]++;
}
int a[1] = {12};
increment(a);
printf("%d", a[0]);
```

The other problem is with variable length arrays, where I used mallocs, which I don't see any other solution than putting arbitrary long and fixed sizes everywhere.

Yes, that seems completely stupid (to me at least) but that's how my teacher wants us to code, or think of things differently perhaps. And if I do such a regex, it will feel like I needed pointers and avoided the problem.

Do you have any ideas?

Or do you know any already existing tool to convert in such a way a C code?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you are far ahead of your teacher, so just ignore them and keep coding properly? Coding in C without using pointers is kind like driving a car without touching the wheel with your hands...

Comment: It's not like I'd have the choice, it's either I accept her constraints... or I fail my exam

Comment: A teacher who punishes students for being too far ahead and learning too quick should be fired. I don't think this is the best place to ask how to code with obfuscated requirements.

Comment: Try asking your teacher what you are supposed to be learning from not using pointers.  If the constraint is simply "because I haven't taught them yet", see if you can convince them that such a constraint does not really serve an educational purpose.

Comment: The thing is, one of the constraint was "saving a game" but my game choice was bomberman which makes absolutely no sense to save and continue later so instead I've made a level editor to save levels. Not games, levels. Then I asked if that was okay and she simply replied "saving a game is mandatory".

Comment: LOL, why you need this increment()? You can't just a++ ? Don't use pointers.

Comment: I don't need this increment, that's just a sample of the new way of writing code I suggest to avoid pointers. I do need pointers.

Comment: I bet your assignment is simple enough to avoid pointers. Accept this challenge.

Comment: My friend, it sounds like you may be facing an unenviable dilemma: Either learn how to program well in C, or get a passing grade in this class.  Sounds like you might not be able to have both.

Comment: I know and that's why I want to convert the code that badly. Hence my question: do you know guys a clever way to do that or will I have to make my own regex?

Comment: Regarding the save-game problem, perhaps you can add a checkpoint mechanic to the game such that you can continue from the last checkpoint.  Even if you don't want it in your game.  Sounds like a terrible assignment to me.  I'd just follow the rules if I were you, and make my own games in my spare time.  Regarding conversion, how much code do you actually have?  Maybe just do it by hand or basic search/replace.  Regex smaller cases if that helps, but don't fall into the trap of designing the one regex to rule them all.

Comment: Alternatively, you could approach the head of department about the issue, if you feel the rules are unfair.

Comment: How is this a trap? I have a dozen of .c/.h files. I already seriously don't make it for me, just for the assignment but whenever I try to make it better, the rules stop me. It wasn't that much important until that new rule of no pointers

Comment: Well I don't see how I could ever win by doing such a thing. A teacher has the rights to teach us and give us assignments as it pleases themself.

Comment: I'm suggesting it's a trap to spend too much time perfecting a single regex to magically convert everything in your code, because in practice that takes longer than simply going through by hand or converting sections with quick find/replace.  But what do I know...  I maintain a code base of a quarter million lines of code.  Do you think that in the time it has taken to ask and discuss on SO, you might've actually been able to convert your code by hand?  Regarding the no-pointers rule, if that was added arbitrarily after the assignment was given, you have cause to approach the HOD about it.

Comment: The rule exists since the beginning. Before being a computer science student, I'm a maths student and I only go to computer courses when I have the time to so I wasn't aware they did not see pointers yet. I learn by myself and then have to adapt the learning to the teacher exams or assignments, so yeah that's my fault. And you're right making a perfectly efficient regex would be a waste of time so I'll just manually do it after the game is done. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful, if the idea is to program whatever without pointer, even and especially if it is not obvious how to do that, then using pointers and hiding them is likely to prevent the actual goal - to learn something which the teacher might actually have designed well into the assignments.